# Installing packages (pywin32) to Python embedded distribution

Tags: package, python-3.5, pywin32

The [Python 3.5 "embedded distribution"](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) is a ZIP file containing

```
pyexpat.pyd
python.exe
python3.dll
python35.dll
python35.zip
pythonw.exe
pyvenv.cfg
select.pyd
sqlite3.dll
unicodedata.pyd
vcruntime140.dll
winsound.pyd
_bz2.pyd
_ctypes.pyd
_decimal.pyd
_elementtree.pyd
_hashlib.pyd
_lzma.pyd
_msi.pyd
_multiprocessing.pyd
_overlapped.pyd
_socket.pyd
_sqlite3.pyd
_ssl.pyd
```

I need to install pywin32

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/
- http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML

The installer requires the specific python version to be installed on the system. Target paths cannot be provided manually.

[image: Dialog]

[image: Selection]

The installer can be unzipped but I am not familiar with the packaging system, so I cannot do a manual install.

I found https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py which manages to get Scripts/pip.exe and creates Lib/site-packages.

But:

```
tools\python
>pip install pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

**Solution moved to answer.**

It would be interesting to know how manually install the package from the the current installer (or how to get the installer to use a specified path).

Comment: [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) fails with current 3.6.1. Issue and workaround: https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/issues/7#issuecomment-274453772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a (slightly older) release of pywin32 as Python wheel at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32

```
> pip.exe install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
  Downloading pypiwin32-219-cp35-none-win32.whl (7.9MB)
    100% |################################| 7.9MB 114kB/s
Installing collected packages: pypiwin32
Successfully installed pypiwin32-219
```

Test:

```
import win32clipboard

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText( 'Hello World!', win32clipboard.CF_TEXT )
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

`> python test.py`

Paste: `Hello World!`